# NSURLConnection asynchronous request cuts off body during send

Tags: iphone, cordova, post, nsurlconnection

I have a method that periodically sends data to a server and receives a response code back. I implemented NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest for it, and it was working with small data fine. I've had a chance to test sending base64 encoded pictures, which is a common task for the app, and am finding that it cuts off after a few characters of the encoded image. Here's the code involved.

```
// Initial setup
NSString *urlStr = @"https://example.com/";
urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]] retain];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// The actual sending part
- (void)sendRequest:(NSString *)reqStr {

@try {
    if (sendRequestStatus == kRequestState_waiting) {
        sendRequestStatus = kRequestState_processing;
        NSString *dataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"request_data=%@",reqStr];
        NSLog(@"datastr is %@",dataStr);
        NSData *dataForUrl = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"nsdata length is: %i",[dataForUrl length]);
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:dataForUrl];
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
          // housekeeping
        }];
    }
}
```

I get no errors in the logs. The log statement that prints out the dataStr prints the correct data. The log statement that prints the length of the data printed out 183384 bytes, which seems appropriate for the picture. On the server however, the post body is cut off a few characters after the start of the encoded image data. An example is `/9j/4` where 4 was the last character the server received.

I'm testing this on an iPhone 3Gs. This is a phonegap application, and testing the same on my Android version has no issues, so the problem must be in my implementation of sending the data. I have not heard any problems from another tester using an iPhone 4 or 4s, so it could be an issue of processing speed. What can I do to tighten this up and prevent the post body from ever cutting off?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but maybe the problem is this:

```
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I would try with this:

```
[urlRequest setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

because you are sending a base 64 encoded string.

Comment: It turned out the data was being interpreted at the other end as url encoded data (probably rightly) and being unencoded. That resulted in the `+` character being received as a space instead. To fix it, I just encoded the data once before sending it off, and the server receives it fine now. I'm not sure if it's apple or IIS not playing nicely. Would your suggestion prevent that server decode?